# Centering the horizontal on the column right so that the text is in the middle of the screen

Tags: css, reactjs, flexbox

```
<div className={css.title} >
        <div className={css.row}>
            <div className={css.columnLeft}>
              <div className={css.header}>Images</div>
            </div>
            <div className={css.columnRight}>
              <strong>Image 1 of 2</strong>
            </div>
        </div>
        <Icon />
      </div>
```

css

```
.row {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.columnLeft {
  flex: 1 0 25%;
  text-align: left;
}

.columnRight {
  flex: 1 0 75%;
}
```

[image]

Currently does

I would like it to be aligned horizontally more so in between left and center.

Comment: An [example] would be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To keep *"Image 1 of 2"* (center column) in the middle of the screen:

- give left and right ***<sup>1</sup>*** columns `flex: 1 1 50%`
- give center column `flex: 0 0 auto`

This will make the left and right columns start flex calculation from a base of `50%` (which gives them equal weight, regardless of unequal content width). The center column will push back against both left and right columns and take an equal amount of empty space from each, to render its contents ***<sup>2</sup>***.

If you want the center column to start wrapping at a particular width, give it a `max-width` and `text-align: center`.

That's about it.

```
<div className={css.title}>
  <div className={css.row}>
    <div className={css.columnLeft}>
      <div className={css.header}>Images</div>
    </div>
    <div className={css.columnCenter}>
      <strong>Image 1 of 2</strong>
    </div>
    <div className={css.columnRight}>
      <Icon />
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```css
.row {
  display: flex;
}
.columnLeft,
.columnRight {
  flex: 1 1 50%;
}
.columnCenter {
  flex: 0 0 auto;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}
.columnRight {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row-reverse;
}
```

---

HTML demo:

```css
.row {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.columnLeft, .columnRight {
  flex: 0 1 50%;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.columnCenter {
  flex: 0 0 auto;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}
.columnRight {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row-reverse;
}
.middle {
  width: 1px;
  height: 2rem;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="columnLeft">
    <div class="header">More content on left side</div>
  </div>
  <div class="columnCenter">
    <strong>I am centered</strong>
  </div>
  <div class="columnRight">Icon</div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="middle" />
</div>
```

---

**Notes:**

***<sup>1</sup>*** - I gave middle flex element `columnCenter` class and placed a `.columnRight` wrapper around the `<Icon />`, because in your example the center element had the class of `columnRight`, which was confusing (e.g: improper naming), IMHO.
***<sup>2</sup>*** - Keep in mind flex is flexible (hence the name). If one of the columns has ***significantly*** more content than the other, the equal pushing of center column against the sides won't be so equal anymore. Sides only concede an equal amount of space as long as they have more room than needed to render their contents. If you want to keep the center text centered no matter what, place `max-width` on the side columns.